# How to do search by option to search from files?

Tags: python, file, text-files

I'm a beginner trying to build a simple library management system using Python. Users can search a book from a list of many books stored in a text file. Here is an example of what is in the text file:

```yaml
Author: J.K Rowling
Title: Harry Potter and the Deathly Hollow
Keywords: xxxx
Published by: xxxx
Published year: xxxx
Author: Stephen King
Title: xxxx
Keywords: xxxx
Published by: xxxx
Published year: xxxx
Author: J.K Rowling
Title: Harry Potter and the Half Blood Prince
Keywords: xxxx
Published by: xxxx
Published year: xxxx
```

This is where it gets difficult for me. There is a `Search by Author` option for the user to search books. What I want to do is when the users search for any authors (e.g. `J.K Rowling`), it would output all (in this case, there are two `J.K Rowling` books) of the related components (`Author`, `Title`, `Keywords`, `Published by`, `Published year`). This is the last piece of the program, which I'm having very much difficulty in doing. Please help me, and thank you all in advance.

Comment: What did you try? Please, spend some time reading ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You will get better results by following the tips in those articles.

Comment: What do the existing parts of your program do? How do you represent the books in your program? The answer to your question must build on that.

Comment: Have a look into using yaml instead of just a normal text file.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible for you to implement the text file in the form of a JSON file instead? It could be a better alternative since you could easily access all the values depending on the key you have chosen and search through those as well.

```
{
"Harry Potter and the Deathly Hollow" : 
    {
    "Author": "J.K Rowling",
    "Keywords": xxxx,
    "Published by": xxxx,
    "Published year": xxxx
    },

'Example 2' : 
    {
    "Author": "Stephen King"
    "Keywords": xxxx
    "Published by": xxxx
    "Published year": xxxx
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, spend some time reading ["How do I write a good answer?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the lines of the text file like this:

```
with open(r"path\to\text_file.txt", "r") as books:
    lines = books.readlines()
    for index in range(len(lines)):
        line = lines[index]
```

Now, get the author of each book by splitting the line on the `":"` character and testing if the first part `== "Author"`. Then, get the second part of the split string and strip it of the `"\n"` [newline] and `" "` characters to make sure there are no extra spaces or anything that will mess up the search on either side. I would also recomment lowercasing the author name and search query to make capitalisation not matter. Test if this is equal to the search query:

```
        if line.split(":")[0] == "Author" and\
           line.split(":")[1].strip("\n ").lower() == search_query.lower():
```

Then, in this if loop, print out all the required information about this book.
Completed code:

```
search_query = "J.K Rowling"
with open(r"books.txt", "r") as books:
    lines = books.readlines()
    for index in range(len(lines)):
        line = lines[index]
        if line.split(":")[0] == "Author" and line.split(":")[1].strip("\n ").lower() == search_query.lower():
            print(*lines[index + 1: index + 5])
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, a lot of problems to be programmed can be resolved into a three-step process:

- Read the input into an internal data structure
- Do processing as required
- Write the output

This problem seems like quite a good fit for that pattern:

- In the first part, read the text file into an in-memory list of either dictionaries or objects (depending on what's expected by your course)
- In the second part, search the in-memory list according to the search criteria; this will result in a shorter list containing the results
- In the third part, print out the results neatly

It would be reasonable to put these into three separate functions, and to attack each of them separately

Answer (score 0):

```
# To read the details from the file ex books.txt
with open("books.txt","r") as fd:
    lines = fd.read()  
#Split the lines based on Author. As Author word will be missing after split so add the Author to the result. The entire result is in bookdetails list.
bookdetails = ["Author" + line for line in lines.split("Author")[1:]]
#Author Name to search
authorName = "J.K Rowling"   
# Search for the given author name from the bookdetails list. Split the result based on new line results in array of details. 
result = [book.splitlines() for book in bookdetails if "Author: " + authorName in book]
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you will always receive this format of the file and you want to transform it into a dictionary:

```
def read_author(file):
    data = dict()
    with open(file, "r") as f:
        li = f.read().split("\n")
        for e in li: 
            if ":" in e:
                data[e.split(":")[0]] = e.split(":")[1]
    return data['Author']
```

> *Note:* The text file sometimes has empty lines so I check if the line contains the colon (:) before transforming it into a dict.

**Then** if you want a more generic method you can pass the KEY of the element you want:

```
def read_info(file, key):
    data = dict()
    with open(file, "r") as f:
        li = f.read().split("\n")
        for e in li: 
            if ":" in e:
                data[e.split(":")[0]] = e.split(":")[1]
    return data[key]
```

Separating the reading like the following you can be more modular:

```
class BookInfo:

    def __init__(self, file) -> None:
        self.file = file
        self.data = None

    def __read_file(self):
        if self.data is None:
            with open(self.file, "r") as f:
                li = f.read().split("\n")
                self.data = dict()
                for e in li: 
                    if ":" in e:
                        self.data[e.split(":")[0]] = e.split(":")[1]
    def read_author(self):
        self.__read_file()
        return self.data['Author']
```

Then create objects for each book:

```
info = BookInfo("book.txt")
print(info.read_author())
```